# How can my Question be improved?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I see someone felt like [my delicious Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/25100/) didn't meet 6 points of decent subjective Questions, and after having a look at [that blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), am curious which of those points did it fall short on?

[**update**] In response to a Comment, here's an expansion:

1. pass
2. not too relevant here; observation is more important than personal experience here (not sure if observation==opinion)
3. pass
4. see (2)
5. see (2)
6. not sure of this one

Anyways, it was interesting to learn about people you might not even, but are having an influence in your life as a programmer. Maybe that's not enough, but then the decision would mean some other Questions got to be closed. I'm here referring to Questions like favorite programming language, or even the [Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/who-is-the-greatest-and-most-influential-programmer-of-all-time) I linked to.

Comment: Which of the points do you think it met?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you've said that points 2, 4 and 5 are "not too relevant here", marked 1 and 3 as "pass" and admitted that you're "not sure" of point 6 would indicate to me that the question certainly doesn't meet enough (or indeed any) of the 6 points to be *relevant* **and** *useful* here on programmers.

Actually I'm not sure of the question you lined to either - but as my close vote would be final I'm not going to do anything with it at the moment.

Comment: Yes, just 2 passes are not enough.

Comment: Is it possible that this Question can be asked in a way in which it can be good enough to be re-opened?

Comment: @Tshepang - edit it and then flag it for moderator attention. We'll take a look and if it's OK re-open it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this sort of question is prone to creating a flame war.  Without adequate guidelines, questions like this tend to spiral into arguments.  You may also want to check rule #6 of the subjective questions guidelines.  I see no practical purpose for this question other than as "mindless social fun."

Comment: +1 for "The question has no point".